# line_profiler installation failed : UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, line-profiler

When trying to install line_profiler *via* `pip install line_profiler`, I keep getting the same error :

```
Installing collected packages: line-profiler
  Running setup.py install for line-profiler ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 107: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 107: invalid start byte
```

Note : I manually added `cl.exe` to the PATH variables, because I couldn't get `vcvarsall.bat x64` to work.

Any idea on how to fix this? I'm using python 3.6: is line_profiler only for python 2.X?